# Approximation of the map $x_{1} = x_{0} + \epsilon f(x_{0})$ by a flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

It is known that an $O( \epsilon)$-close to identity map $x_{1} = x_{0} + \epsilon f(x_{0})$, where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, is approximated by a time-$\epsilon$ map along a level curve of a certain autonomous flow. If $f \in C^{\infty}$, then it can be approximated to $O(\epsilon^{j})$ for arbitrary large $j$. If $f$ is analytic, then the error can be made exponentially small in $\epsilon$.

I am aware of the fact that the above result is obtained from the averaging theory for odes, however I don't know how to prove it. I'd be grateful if someone could provide a sketch of the proof or some references to published literature where this result is proved.

Also, how would the above accuracy change if $f \in C^{m}$ for some finite $m$? Does it then follow that the map is approximated to $O(\epsilon^{m})$?

Comment: Prove exactly what? That is it possible to formally invert the Butcher B-series of the Euler method? That the partial sums of that series do indeed provide continuous trajectories that approximate the discrete trajectory of the Euler method to the given order? See Hairer et al on [backward error analysis](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/polycop.html) for numerical ODE solvers and Butchers [miniature 15](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/miniature/miniature15.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. What I want is a proof that close to identity diffeomorphism $T_{\epsilon}(x) = x + \epsilon f(x) + O(\epsilon^{2})  $ can be embedded in a flow  $\phi$ of an ode; and also I need to check up to what order in the small parameter $\epsilon$ the given diffeomorphism $T_{\epsilon}$ and a time-$\epsilon$ map of the flow, $\phi^{\epsilon}$ can be made to coincide depending on the differentiability of $T$.  One reference that is somewhat relevant is Neishtadt's 1984 paper "The separation of motions in systems with rapidly rotating phase" but he deals with analytic systems... @LutzL

Comment: If $\dot x=g(x)=g_0(x)+ϵg_1(x)+ϵ^2g_2(x)$ then $x(ϵ)=x_0+ϵg(x_0)+\frac{ϵ^2}2g'g+\frac{ϵ^3}6(g''[g,g]+g'^2g)+…$. Insertion and coefficient identification gives $g_0=f$, $g_1+\frac12g_0'g_0=0$, $g_2+\frac12(g_0'g_1+g_1'g_0)+\frac16(g_0''[g_0,g_0]+g_0'^2g_0)$ etc. leading to $$g(x)=f(x)-\frac{ϵ}2f'(x)f(x)+\frac{ϵ^2}{12}(4f'(x)^2f(x)+f''(x)[f(x),f(x)])$$ etc. This method can be continued to any order as long as $f$ remains differentiable.

Comment: I see; hence if $f \in C^{m}$, then the map and flow coincide up to and including terms in $O(\epsilon^{m+1})$, right? @LutzL